# Why is WiX detecting Windows Installer 4.05 when 4.5 is installed?

Tags: windows-vista, wix, windows-installer

This is a bit of a strange problem. I have an installer that needs to check the version of Windows Installer on a machine, so I use the VersionMsi property to do this.

However, when trying it out on a Vista 32-bit machine, I have found that it reports that I have 4.05 installed. So I checked msi.dll, msiexec, etc and found that they were all at 4.5.

There must be a registry value or something else that is still pointing to 4.05, so I was wondering if there is a way to safely rollback to 4.05 and then apply the update again?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for **InstallerVersion** attribute of the wix [Package element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_package.htm) shows a hint (emphasis added by me):

> The minimum version of the Windows
>   Installer required to install this
>   package. Take the major version of the
>   required Windows Installer and
>   multiply by a 100 then add the minor
>   version of the Windows Installer. For
>   example, "200" would represent Windows
>   Installer 2.0 and **"405" would
>   represent Windows Installer 4.5.** For
>   64-bit Windows Installer packages,
>   this property must be set to 200 or
>   greater.

Also, if you think about it, `4.05` and `4.5` are exactly the same if you interpret the dot as a number separator rather than a decimal point. `05` is just a way to write `5` with two digits in that case.

Comment: oh wow thanks dude, I'd never have found that in a million years :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's something weird going on inside WiX and/or your registry since the "05" portion is neither, so to speak, Microsoft nor generally accepted way of versioning products.

Comment: It's quite strange as I've just tried updating a Windows XP machine that had 3.0 on it using the Windows Installer 4.5 hotfix, and it also reported 4.05. I'm now thinking whether it would be possible that the VersionMsi property itself is incorrectly detecting 4.5 as 4.05